# Programming functionality for an android app widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a simple flashlight application and I would like to have the light switch on-off functionality by simply clicking on the widget also.

Now when I click on the widget my program starts, it is ok but it would be better to reach the functionality of my app directly from the widget.

I think now the appwidgetprowider just starts my activity:

> Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

In my flashlight`s main activity I switch on the led of the phone by the

> switchOnTheFlash()

method.

Does anyone have an idea, how could I start this method from the widget?

Thank you and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent is not needed to turn on the flashlight as it will always take you somewhere in activities or actions. The simplest thing to do is make your `switchOnTheFlash()` function `static` like this -

```
public static void switchOnTheFlash() {
    // Your Function
}
```

and Now you can call this function from any activity just like -

```
YourACtivity.switchOnTheFlash();
```

**If Errors Occur --**

Make sure that all the variables you use in `switchOnTheFlash()` should be **static** too or you will be getting error like `cannot use non-static variables in static function` (or may be somewhat written a bit different).

Another error, if you use functions like `getResources()` you can get errors. To get rid, Just make a `static Context mContext;` globally and initialize it like `mContext = this;` in `OnCreate`. Then simply replace `mContext.getResources()...` everywhere in your function `switchOnTheFlash()`.

Cheers!